# In 20.04 LTS sometimes most of my keyboard keys do not work

Tags: keyboard

every then and now most of my keys do not work. Like the alphanumeric keys and also some others like delete. And then I press first different keys and later wildly on all of them and suddenly the keyboard works again. But I have no clue why. Do you know about a software bug that correspond with that? I also had that on a different laptop with 18.04 a while ago.

Best regards

**Edit:** In both cases, I speak of laptop keyboards. Everytime Lenovo T-series.

Comment: please [edit] your question. Is the offending keyboard a USB device, PS2 or a laptop keyboard? I have used USB and PS2 keyboards on 16.04, 18.04, 20.04 and 21.04 (MATE) with no issues whatsoever so this could be a hardware problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I updated the opening post.

Comment: Perhaps a cable or connector issue, Do other keyboards on a USB port display the same problem?

Comment: I have not tested that yet.